# How to edit a database in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to store a object java custom class to a database using SQLiteOpenHelper when I click on save button in an activity class (Class A); and the object will be store into an ArrayList and display on a listview in other class (Class B) by using Bundle and Intent to pass by.

However, I dont know how to pass the existed object in the ArrayList in class B back to class A so that I can retrieve information and edit the object.

Comment: What do you actually want to do, passing the object or list of object?

Comment: I want to edit the a specific object by clicking it on the listview.

Comment: Now what I understand is that you want to pass the specific object to another class to edit that object...am I right?

Comment: It would help if you pasted some code to show what two classes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText in ListView layout and  make edittext clickable true when you click listitem.